# How to put a label after a return statement in Lua?

Tags: lua, return, goto

The following results in a syntax error on the third line:

```
function f()
    return
    ::x::   
end
```

Why is it not possible to have a label following a return statement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A return statement must be the last statement in a block, so just put the return statement in a block:

```
function f()
    do
        return
    end
    ::x::   
end
```

Comment: Well, have two upvotes. Did you just run over it in the wild, in the manual, or where?

Comment: @Deduplicator I stumbled upon the problem while generating Lua code, and I found in the manual that a return statement can only be the last statement in a block.

Comment: Well, I found it sometime when I ate the manual. What would really interest me though is the reason *why* they added that restriction. I mean, it's not really intuitive and would at first look require extra-effort to maintain...

Comment: @Deduplicator: It strikes me as a reasonable restriction, since any code after a `return` statement cannot be executed, and allowing statements to follow a `return` could be a source of errors. (`goto`s mean that's not always true, but apparently the language rules don't bend over backwards to make `goto`s convenient.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: Sure, iff there were no `goto`s, but they were introduced. At which time the set of things one reasonably expects to be able to write after it extended from "comments till end of block" to "comments till end of block or jump-label. Even if the language says otherwise. Now if they had made `return` an end-of-block-marker like `end`...

Comment: @Deduplicator: Otherwise the code could be ambiguous (e.g. `return print(x)` -- tail call or `return` before unreachable function call?!), and even if it wasn't ambiguous, it could require a lot of look-ahead to figure that out (e.g. `return a[1][2][3] = true`). The Lua authors *could* make an exception for labels because you cannot return labels from functions, but so far they are normal statements, and so the restriction holds.