# Why a label after a return cause syntax error?

Tags: lua, label, syntax-error

With Lua 5.4:

```
function f()
  return 1
  ::LABEL::
end
print(f())
```

I got error:

```
lua: _.lua:3: 'end' expected (to close 'function' at line 1) near '::'
```

while

```
function f()
  if true then return 1 end
  ::LABEL::
end
print(f())
```

works fine.

I don't understand that error.

Comment: I assume it's connected to tail calls. The first one could be optimized, the second one can't. A label would prevent that optimization. Interestingly, both examples compile to the same bytecode as per https://lua-bytecode.github.io/compiler.html

Comment: Similar question with some discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258306/how-to-put-a-label-after-a-return-statement-in-lua

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Labels syntactically are statements. This can be seen from the grammar in the [reference manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#9):

```
stat ::= label | ...
```

A `return` statement is syntactically required to be the last statement in a block:

```lua
block ::= {stat} [retstat]
```

The following Lua code would throw a similar syntax error:

```lua
function f()
    return
    x = 1
end
```

simply because the assignment `x = 1`, a statement just like labels, comes after the `return`. Simply put, `return ...` *must be* followed by `end`. The rationale for this presumably is that Lua doesn't want to allow "dead code" (although this isn't really valid for labels); IIRC it also resolves a syntactical ambiguity.

If you wrap the `return` in a block, the syntax error is fixed - the `return` now is the last statement in the block, there are no "dead statements" after it:

```lua
function f()
    if 1 then return end -- return is followed by end - all is well (syntactically)!
    x = 1 -- this is still dead code (semantically)
end
```

Lua can't and won't semantically analyze your code to determine that the assignment to `x` is still dead code.

This is used for quick'n'dirty insertion of early `return`s during debugging: You can simply wrap them in `do` ... `end`:

```lua
function f()
    do return end -- syntactically valid, equivalent to commenting out the rest of the function
    x = 1
end
```

Comment: Your first example works fine. Add `;` after `return` to make the point.

Comment: @lhf thanks for pointing this out, switched to an assignment `x = 1` to make things clearer (`return; g()` would technically be `return` followed by two statements, one of which is just the semicolon).